# Consulta SQL con diferentes condiciones en un solo campo

Tags: sql

quiero hacer una consulta donde al escribir el nombre y marca del producto me salga los resultados pero el nombre del producto y la marca están situados en diferentes columnas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo: al escribir en un campo de texto en este caso en un TextBox **"BROCA BOSCH"** quiero que me salga los resultados que contengan ese nombre y marca.

Intenté hacer de esta manera pero no me resultó.

*Primera forma*

```
create proc sp_BuscarProductos
@filtro varchar(60)
as
select P.ProductoID, P.Codigo, P.Nombre, P.Potencia, P.Marca, P.Stock,
P.PrecioCompra, P.PrecioVenta, P.PrecioPublico, P.Fecha
from Productos P
where P.Nombre + P.Marca like @filtro+'%'
```

*Segunda forma*

```
create proc sp_BuscarProductos
@filtro varchar(60)
as
select P.ProductoID, P.Codigo, P.Nombre, P.Potencia, P.Marca, P.Stock,
P.PrecioCompra, P.PrecioVenta, P.PrecioPublico, P.Fecha
from Productos P
where P.Nombre like @filtro+'%' and P.Marca like @filtro+'%'
```

Comment: Que has intentado?, Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Puedes tratar de hacer esto. `where P.Nombre like @filtro+'%' or P.Marca like '%'+@filtro+'%' `

Comment: TheOligarch Pero en ese caso no obtendría resultados escribiendo el nombre y la marca sino tendría que ingresar el nombre o la marca en el campo de búsqueda

Comment: Si quieres el nombre Y la marca, cambia el `OR` por un `AND`

Comment: ¿Es posible que escriban "BROCA BOSCH" y " BOSCH BROCA"? ¿Es posible que escriban "BROCAS de la marca BOSCH"? si todas estas formas son válidas y esperarías obtener algún resultado, me temo que con SQL estándar no es posible resolverlo o no al menos de una forma natural. Necesitarías un indizado textual, creo que todos los motores implementan algo de esto.